# Assign values on multi-properties to a object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a object which it was initialized before in a base class. In inherited class, I use this object and assign values on multi-properties to it. Example:

```
this.Chart.X = 10;
this.Chart.Y = 10;
this.Chart.Width = 20;
this.Chart.Height = 20;
this.Chart.Background = Color.Red;
```

However, I must repeat "this.Chart" many times. How to avoid this. Note that I don't want to re-create this object again because in the base class, it was initialized with some common values.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the values coming from?  What are you trying to avoid exactly?  The code you have right now looks just fine.

Comment: You don't need the `this.` But that's probably not what you are looking for. C# does not have the equivalent of VB's `With obj`. Outside of object initialization, there is no real shorthand available.

Comment: If you have many properties to explicitly set, you can't really get around the assignments

Comment: I am thinking to the keyword 'with' but it can't be in C#. Why Microsoft doesn't support it?

Comment: I must to use 'this' because of the coding convention, my project is being applied StyleCop.

Comment: @LuLu, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/11/why-doesn-t-c-have-vb-net-s-with-operator.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a set of extension methods for `Chart` that implement a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It will get rid of some of the repeated code, so your example could looks something like:

```
this.Chart.X(10).Y(10).Width(20).Height(20).Background(Color.Red);
```

And you don't even need `this`.

Comment: I would recommend using the Set prefix for the methods. Like this: `this.Chart.SetX(10).SetY(10).SetWidth(20).SetHeight(20).SetBackground(Color.Red);` See the C# example in Brian's link. IMO the Java-style setter prefix makes it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @PaulSasik: I agree. Another common option is `With` as in `WithX`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really desperate to save some typing you could write a function to do it:

```
static void InitializeChart(Chart c) {
  c.X = 10;  
  c.Y = 10;  
  c.Width = 20;  
  c.Height = 20;  
  c.Background = Color.Red; 
}
```

Or just assign the chart to a local variable:

```
  var c = this.Chart;
  c.X = 10;  
  c.Y = 10;  
  c.Width = 20;  
  c.Height = 20;  
  c.Background = Color.Red;
```

A different approach, if you have control of the base class, is to provide some initialization parameters to it and set the properties to the right values when constructing the Chart.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a field initializer like this:

```
this.chart = new Chart {X = 10, Y = 10, Width = 20, Height = 20, Background = Color.Red};
```

It saves you the hassle of doing, this.chart.X = blah, this.chart.Y = blah...

Comment: This solution require the object must be re-created, which I don' want. Please read my question carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that in your question.  Your only real options are then to either create a method which updates the class with optional paramaters, or deal with having to "ctrl-v" "this.Chart" and press "." ;)